# how to write tests for get requests in jest

Tags: node.js, rest, express, jestjs

I am testing API'S with JEST. I don't understand how I'm going to pass values to parameters in GET request.

```js
describe("Refresh Token", () => {
  it("Refresh Token", async() => {
    const response = await request(app).get("/refreshtoken");
    expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
    expect(response.body.data).toEqual("hd$snndm12cdj2#Efvvxv");
  });
})
```

In the above case, the output is expected as the given string. But the output is undefined. Besides that what I should do if I have multiple parameters. Below code is my post request code which is working perfectly. I want to pass multiple parameters as I defined in the post request.

```js
describe('Set Profile Image', () => {
  it('Set Profile Image', async() => {
    const res = await request(app)
      .post('/setProfileImage')
      .send({
        profileID: "1234",
        profileImage: "fnsdjnfsnf"
      })
    expect(res.status).toBe(200)
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the params in the URL of your request:

```
 const response = await request(app).get("/refreshtoken?param1=123")
```

To pass multiple parameters, just do this:

```
const response = await request(app).get("/refreshtoken?param1=123&param2=234")
```